# Xcode FacebookSDK retrieving friend's list

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app using XCode where I retrieve the user's friends and display it back to them. The user can login in no problem (it will even display their facebook name and profile picture) but I am having trouble getting their Friends list.

I am currently using this code:

```
[friendRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary* result, NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d friends", friends.count]);
    for (FBGraphObject<FBGraphUser> *friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"%@ is a friend", friend.name);
    }}];
```

Running this will output "Hello" and then "0 friends"

I've tried many other methods of doing this that I've found online and none have worked so far. Even using the code in the FriendPickerSample in the Facebook SDK folder doesn't work (tbh the FriendPickerSample doesn't work for some reason when I run it either).

TL;DR: I'm looking for a way to get a facebook user's friends and nothing has worked so far. It may be something silly that I'm just missing.

Comment: Facebook API v2.0 only gives you friends that also uses the app. I suggest searching because there is like a hundred questions about this

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the v2.0 of the Graph API. With that, you only get the list of friends returnes which also use the same App as the Access Token-requesting Application.

This has been asked dozens of times during the last few weeks. Please use the search of SO the next time first. E.g.

[How to pull a user's friends from Facebook (with v 2.0 Facebook Auth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530566/how-to-pull-a-users-friends-from-facebook-with-v-2-0-facebook-auth/23538051#23538051)

Comment: Is there another version of the Graph API that let's you retrieve all the friends ?

Comment: @Macaret Graph API v1.0 is gone since April 30th, 2015. So, no.

Comment: I see that i can see all friends by requesting taggable_friends, but i don't think these taggable friends can be invited to my app. Is this true ?

Comment: @Macaret That what https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/ is for, but `...only available to Games, and requires the user_friends permission`